# How do you turn on Dark Mode on this unix.stackexchange.com web site?

Tags: discussion

Even though my browser (Vivaldi) is set to display web pages in dark mode, when it comes to unix.stackexchange.com it just displays in bright white.

Is there a way to turn the Dark Mode On on unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Are you aware of greasemonkey/tampermonkey ?